# Load module params joomla in external files without care the current page

Tags: php, css, joomla, module, parameters

I'm trying to develop a css file where we load properties defined in my module configuration.

I found the documentation => http://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/getModule

But if the module is not active on all page, I can't get params of the module in my option.css.php

On my test, I use my module only on my homepage.

My code => http://pastebin.com/DSLR67qT

This code work only if I put my module display on all page in Joomla.